# Error installing Safari for Windows on Ubuntu 15 through Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, safari, wine

I'm trying to install Safari 5 for Windows in Ubuntu 15 through Wine (version 1.6.2).

First I downloaded with wget:

> wget http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

Then I executed:

> wine SafariSetup.exe

And I get this:

```
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why would you want to run Safari for Windows when Apple haven't supported it for 2yrs?

Comment: I'm a web developer, I want to run Safari on Ubuntu, to test web pages.

Comment: can you put your WINE version in your question? I'm reading this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1414995

Comment: Safari has changed a lot since v5 - I'm not sure even if you get it running it will provide you with accurate feedback.